# Sending form data within an email Django

Tags: django, django-forms

Hey i have a form on django and need to send the results out in an email. now the email works and the form works.

The only thing i do not like is the way the data is displayed i have tried using tuples and lists to send the data.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        standard = form.cleaned_data['standard']
        atex = form.cleaned_data['ATEX']
        supply_type = form.cleaned_data['supply_type']
        line_frequency = form.cleaned_data['line_frequency']
        supply_voltage = form.cleaned_data['supply_voltage']
        power = form.cleaned_data['power']
        poles = form.cleaned_data['poles']
        mounting = form.cleaned_data['mounting']
        efficiency = form.cleaned_data['efficiency']
        protection = form.cleaned_data['protection']
        frame = form.cleaned_data['frame']
        brake = form.cleaned_data['brake']
        force_cooling = form.cleaned_data['force_cooling']
        encoder = form.cleaned_data['encoder']
        form = [str(message), ('Standard',str(standard))]

        if subject and message and from_email:
            try:
                send_mail(subject, str(form), from_email, ['jordanfeatherstone@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            messages.success(request, 'Enquiry email successfully sent')
            return render(request, 'motors.html', {'motors': motors, 'form': form})
```

What would be the best way to manipulate the results in a human readable way?

Comment: Why don't you use a template?

Comment: You are fetching ALL these data just to send `message` and `standard` as the body of the email? Or the rest fields are used somewhere else?

Comment: @nik_m I am trying to send all the data within the email, but everyway i have tried has given me encoded text, erros or just horrific unreadable way :P

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'll look into that now, thanks.

Comment: As @J.Featherstone mentions, you would better use an email template to fit your needs!

Comment: @nik_m Okay thanks, ill look into it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for a boost here is a quick walkthrough:

If you're just try to send [plain text](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/templates/#django.template.loader.render_to_string) then things are quite easy.

```
# views.py

from django.template.loader import render_to_string

# Put all the form data inside a dict, apart from the ones that will
# not be included inside the email. Just for better readiness.
context = {
    standard: form.cleaned_data['standard'],
    ...
}
# Build the .txt file with the context data just like you build HTML templates!
plain_message = render_to_string('path/to/your/email/template.txt', context)

send_mail(subject, plain_message, from_email, ['jordanfeatherstone@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

If you want a HTML template with images, styling etc then things are more complicated and deserve a new question in SO.

Comment: Thank you for that good sir! you have helped me conquer my quest!

Comment: Glad that helped you. Best regards!